# Absolute position looks to its closest ancestor, does it care about siblings?

Tags: css, position, absolute, siblings

Summary: Does an absolutely positioned element care about its siblings under any circumstance (Whether the siblings are relative, absolute, static) ?

My understanding was that absolute positioning ignores siblings.

```css
.absoluteBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  /* 
why is top 0 necessary?
If i do not set it, the inner yellow box will position itself after the grey box
The grey box has no position property assigned to it, and even if it did, it should not matter
  -- because the inner-absolute box should just be looking to its ancestor for its position
*/
}

.greyBox {
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="absoluteBox">
  outer yellow box
  <div class="greyBox"></div>
  <div class="absoluteBox">
    inner yellow box should completely fill up screen
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a container ("Outer-Container"). Absolute position, 100% x 100% width and height. It takes up the whole screen in the jsFiddle as it should.

I put a child into "Outer-Container", no position related properties. ("greyBox" in the fiddle).

I then put another Absolute 100x100 div inside the "Outer-Container". Call this "Inner-Container."

PROBLEM: Why does the Inner-Container position itself after the greyBox? It should ignore siblings, be taken out of the normal "flow" of positioning, and just look to its closest positioned ancestor (Outer-Container) when determining its position.

Comment: If the `absolute` element has no position properties (top, right, bottom, left) then it will fall into place according to it's location in the HTML as a normal element.

Comment: This behaviour makes more sense after thinking about it. Thank you

Comment: I've explained this in more detail in an answer.

Comment: did any of the solutions solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

If `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` properties are ***NOT*** defined on a `position: absolute` element, the element will be positioned according to it's location in the HTML.

So the `position: absolute` element cares about it's preceding siblings in that it will use the preceding siblings to determine it's position in the layout.

But the `position: absolute` element ***DOES*** effect the layout of succeeding siblings, and the size of the `position: absolute` element's parent.

Succeeding siblings of the `position: absolute` element will ignore it and position themselves as if the `position: absolute` element is not present.

And the `position: absolute` element's parent will not preserve space for any `absolute` children. So even if the `absolute` element is larger than it's parent, the parent will not grow to contain the `absolute` element.

```css
.absoluteBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.absoluteBox2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.greyBox {
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="absoluteBox">
  outer yellow box
  <div class="greyBox"></div>
  <div class="absoluteBox2">
    inner yellow box should completely fill up screen
  </div>
  <div class="greyBox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#abs-non-replaced-height

Removing the fluff, you see specs like "If `top` and `bottom` **are** auto and `height` is **not** auto, then set top to the static position, then solve for bottom."

What this means is that it defaults to it's `position: static` values, which is what you see since it has no inherited or explicit reference. Brett defined this pretty well actually. The `position: static` values are from where the element is originally drawn - so preceding children are taken into account to calculate the `position: static` value, but proceeding children are not, and get placed as if the absolute element doesn't exist in the DOM flow.

A bit tedious, but there's a bunch of CSS spec rules that make even less sense (opacity affecting z-index for instance, or the fact that percentage based **vertical padding** is relative to it's parent element's **width** not height...)

Comment: in a component I'm working currently has the same issue, does anyone have a solution for this please ? @Xhynk